# NSTimer with error message?

Tags: ios, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I am trying to implement a NSTimer counting down from 5 seconds. But I am getting the message "No known class method for selector scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats....." What am I missing? If you look at the bottom of MTPopupWindow.m in method -void(showInView) you will find the code where the error emerges.

Regards

**MTPopupWindow.h**

```
@class MTPopupWindow;

@protocol MTPopupWindowDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void) willShowMTPopupWindow:(MTPopupWindow*)sender;
- (void) didShowMTPopupWindow:(MTPopupWindow*)sender;
- (void) willCloseMTPopupWindow:(MTPopupWindow*)sender;
- (void) didCloseMTPopupWindow:(MTPopupWindow*)sender;
@end

@interface MTPopupWindow : UIView

+(MTPopupWindow*)showWindowWithHTMLFile:(NSString*)fileName;
+(MTPopupWindow*)showWindowWithHTMLFile:(NSString*)fileName insideView:(UIView*)view;
- (void)timerFireMethod; 
-(void)showInView:(UIView*)v;
+(void)setWindowMargin:(CGSize)margin;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* fileName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWebView* webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <MTPopupWindowDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL usesSafari;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer* timer;
@end
```

**MTPopupWindow.m**

```
#import "MTPopupWindow.h"
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"
#define kCloseBtnDiameter 30
#define kDefaultMargin 18
static CGSize kWindowMarginSize;

@interface MTPopupWindow() <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
UIView* _dimView;
UIView* _bgView;
UIActivityIndicatorView* _loader;
NSTimer *timer;
}
@end

@interface MTPopupWindowCloseButton : UIButton
+ (id)buttonInView:(UIView*)v;
@end

@interface UIView(MTPopupWindowLayoutShortcuts)
-(void)replaceConstraint:(NSLayoutConstraint*)c;
-(void)layoutCenterInView:(UIView*)v;
-(void)layoutInView:(UIView*)v setSize:(CGSize)s;
-(void)layoutMaximizeInView:(UIView*)v withInset:(float)inset;
-(void)layoutMaximizeInView:(UIView*)v withInsetSize:(CGSize)insetSize;
@end

@implementation MTPopupWindow

@synthesize fileName = _fileName;
@synthesize webView = _webView;
@synthesize usesSafari = _usesSafari;
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize timer;

-(void)showInView:(UIView*)v
{
.......
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 taget:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

<---No class method for selector scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector....

```
}

-(void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)theTimer{

NSLog(@"bla bla time is out");
MTPopupWindowCloseButton* btnClose = [MTPopupWindowCloseButton buttonInView:self];
[btnClose addTarget:self action:@selector(closePopupWindow) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

Comment: If you just want to run this in once, then you should use [self performSelector:@selector(YourMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled 'target' as 'taget' in your method call. Do:

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Instead.

Comment: Cheers! The smallest mistakes are often the hardest ones!

Answer (score -1):

The method in .h file is: - (void)timerFireMethod; 
But at the selector is: timerFireMethod:
With ":" at the end but there is no parameter, that is the reason.

Your definition between h file and m file is not consistence.
Please correct the timerFireMethod method.

Comment: That might cause an incomplete implementation warning, but not this particular error. The selector specified to the timer is the same as the one implemented, so it shouldn't cause a crash at run time either.

Comment: Do you see the error message?  "No known class method for selector